# How to play videos in format AVI, FLV and Mp4 stored as BLOB in database using php?

Tags: php, video, blob, playback, avi

I have some uploaded videos of different format .avi, .flv and .mp4 (<2 MB) in MySql database as BLOB.

```php
$name = $_FILES['video']['name'];
$type = $_FILES['video']['type'];
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['video']['tmp_name']);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO VIDEO (name, type, data) VALUES (:name, :type, :data)");
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':name' => $name,
    ':type' => $type,
    ':data' => $data
));
```

Now i want to play them in browser. I'm able to play the .mp4 videos but not any of avi or flv. I hope you could help me with them. The code I used :

```php
$stmt = $pdo->query("Select * from video");
$videos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($videos as $video) {
    echo '<div content="Content_Type:'. $video['type'].'">';
    echo '<video width="400" height="200" controls="controls">';
    echo '<source src ="data:'.$video['type'].';base64,'.base64_encode($video['data']).'" type="'.$video['type'].'"/>';
    echo '</video>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Ps : Video Tag doesn't support these extensions I guess and I know it's not recommended to upload videos in database but it is what it is.

Comment: Browsers only support mp4 no matter how you embed it.

Comment: @KUMAR does browser support conversation via some way. Because I have to store videos with .avi extension and others.